# MongoDB: FailedToParse: Bad characters in value

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

mongodump command:

```
mongodump --host myhost.com --port 12345 --username myUsername --password PSWRD --out /opt/somepath --db myDb --collection my_collection --query "{ content_type_id: { \$not: { \$eq: db.my_type.findOne({slug: 'form_submissions'} )._id } } }" --verbose
```

Results in:

```
assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Bad characters in value:
```

```
offset:33 of:{ content_type_id: { $not: { $eq: db.my_type.findOne({slug: 'form_submissions'} )._id } } }
```

Comment: What does '._id' at the end of query mean??

Comment: @vmr, it returns `ObjectId` of the record, something like `ObjectId('abcd1234xyzd')`

Comment: Does not seem to be an issue at the moment

Answer (score 1):

That's not a valid query. `--query` must be a JSON document. Your error is in thinking that mongodump is something programmatic like the mongo shell that can evaluate the `findOne` and substitute the value into the query. This is not the case. You can find the `_id` from the result of the `findOne` and put it in the mongodump `--query` manually. Use [extended JSON format](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) for an ObjectId type, if that is the type of `_id`.